# SVN not update file after name change

Tags: svn

I have situation. I had two files:

```
File.js // file was modificated 10.06.2015
File2.js // file was modificated 10.06.2015
```

After few days I changed a files content and name.

```
file.js // file was modificated 20.06.2015
file2.js // file was modificated 20.06.2015
```

On my hard drive I have 2 files with green svn icon. So repo is actual.
These are my to files:

```
file.js // file was modificated 20.06.2015
file2.js // file was modificated 20.06.2015
```

When I enter to repo browser I have 4 files.

```
File.js // file was modificated 10.06.2015
File2.js // file was modificated 10.06.2015

file.js // file was modificated 20.06.2015
file2.js // file was modificated 20.06.2015
```

When I commit and rebuild the project I always have old files:

```
File.js // file was modificated 10.06.2015
File2.js // file was modificated 10.06.2015
```

How Can I repair it?

Comment: I think you said you've committed. When's the last time you ran `svn up`?

Comment: How did you rename the files?  Did you `mv File.js file.js`, or did you `svn rename File.js file.js`?

Comment: i renamed it in visual studio and commit it by ankhsvn

Comment: I made commit 10 munutes ago

Answer (score 0):

This is a lower and upper case issue and varies with the Operating System you are on. Windows not being case sensitive, cannot find the difference between `file.js` and `File.js`. In case you are using Windows, if you see, the commit didn't actually happen.

Refer this for the workout: http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#case-change